# MSBuild lock files when build finish for 15 mins

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

My build is failing if I start build after build. msbuild process locks files after the build was finished for 15 min.
Has someone encountered this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set a parameter for msbuild:

Use `msbuild` with `/nr:false`.

From the [msbuild command line interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx):

**/nodeReuse:value** `/nr:value`

Enable or disable the re-use of MSBuild nodes. You can specify the following values:

- True. Nodes remain after the build finishes so that subsequent builds can use them (default).
- False. Nodes don't remain after the build completes.

A node corresponds to a project that’s executing. If you include the /maxcpucount switch, multiple nodes can execute concurrently.

Comment: Hi , Thanks on the answer , i try to use with this switch  , but its not solve this problem